# neovim remapping . to ;

Tags: vim, mapping, neovim

I have remapped quite a few things so far in Neovim. I like to use `f` with `,` and `;` to navigate to a specific character. But, I am trying to experiment with `;` being a leader key and I wanted `.` to take its place. This will allow me to use `f` with `,` and `.` to navigate to the desired character. But, `noremap . ;` doesn't change the behavior of `.`. `,` and `;` continue to work with `f` instead of `,` and `.`.

I expected to be able to use `f` and `,` to navigate backwards and `f` and `.` to navigate forwards.

[,.; continue to behave normally despite this being in my init.vim file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3DVx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`noremap`???? Since you said you have remapped quite a few things in Neovim. I assume that was a typo and what you actually meant was `nnoremap` there.

You must know the **dangers** of mapping `.` to `;` first, which will make the *normal behaviour* of `.` to be lost (i.e. you will not be able to use the "repeat the last command with `.`") unless you map something else to `.` as well.

**First step** to your problem would be mapping with `.` to `;`, which means whenever you type `.` in normal mode, it will behave as if you had actually typed `;`(functionality of `;` command in normal mode will be copied to `.` character) :-

`nnoremap . ;`

(This works for me, I use Neovim as well, It **HAS** to be the typo.)

> `,` and `;` continue to work with `f` instead of `,` and `.`

At this point, `.` should be able to use `.` as `;`, but since you haven't mapped `;` to anything at this point, `;` will functoin as before. Now, The **second step** would be mapping `;` as leader key. Which will make `;` lose its normal functionality, and you will not be able to use `;` to jump to the next search character.

`let mapleader = ";"`

Put the code above in your **init.vim** to make `;` you leader key.

Comment: I really appreciate your quick response. I must have really done a number with my init.vim file or plugins. But, ',', '.', and ';' continue to behave normally despite the code suggested being in my init.vim file. I might have to start from the basics and see if I can get it to work with no plugins. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try running `:nnoremap . ;` as an ex command. If it works as an ex command but doesn't when included in your config file. Then your logic might be correct.